# Why do we have nullptr but not nullchar?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, nullptr

My understanding - and I'm sure I'm about to learn - is that `nullptr` was added to C++ to formalise the convention that a zero value for a pointer means the pointer does not point to a valid object. Is there a case for (or against) adding a corresponding `nullchar` to formalise the convention that a zero value for a char means the char is not a valid character but is instead the terminator of a string? I can see a few things which the two cases have in common:

Type safety: `0` can have several different types, so it's easy to mistakenly assign a non-pointer variable to zero instead of the pointer variable you meant to. It's also easy to call the wrong overloaded function if you get it just right. Having a special and strongly-typed value prevents this kind of mistake, and this could be true for `char` types as well.

Expressiveness: Assigning a variable to be `nullptr` makes it clear to the reader that the variable is a pointer (because only a pointer can be assigned to that value) and that it points to no object. Assigning a char to `nullchar` would add the same kind of clarity and readability.

There's more, but I'm sure you get the idea. So why do we have `nullptr` but not `nullchar`?

Comment: Sometimes a `'\0'` is a valid character.

Comment: `'\0'` is a very cromulent `char`.

Comment: If you want, you can make it yourself! Put this in one of your 'global' headers: `static inline constexpr char nullchar = '\0';`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, what does _cromulent_ mean?

Comment: @Enrico perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Adequate is also cromulent.

Comment: @Enrico -- www.google.com is very cromulent for figuring out what cromulent means.

Comment: I expected to find it on [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/cromulent), but it's not there, so I didn't search with google, thinking it could be a typo. However, thanks for pointing me to the Simpsons.

Comment: Can you please give examples in your question reenforcing why you think a nullchar is a good idea?  I personally don't see a need

Comment: Always happy to see people embiggen their vocabulary.

Comment: You can also use `char{}` as the null char.

Comment: `\0` terminates c strings or string literals, but not a `std::string`. The `\0` is a valid character in a `std::string` and could occur at any position.

Comment: @Eljay But 0 is a valid value for a pointer as well. Both pointers and chars give a special meaning to this one value.

Comment: Pointers give special meaning to zero.  Chars do not give special meaning to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because there's not as much reason to, really. `nullptr` was added to remove the need of the `NULL` macro, which in C is defined as something like `(void*)0`. In C, `void*` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type, so this would work. However, this is not true in C++, which removed this implicit convertibility (but not its inverse, from any pointer type to `void*`), to increase type safety. However, C++ still wanted to have an easy way to make any pointer a null pointer, which is why `nullptr_t` was introduced, which is implicitly convertible to any pointer type like `void*` once was, BUT can only contain the null pointer value, `nullptr`. In C++ you can represent a null character with `'\0'` with no type ambiguity or unnecessary explicit conversions, so there's no reason for a `nullchar` value, which would also take up another valuable reserved identifier (standard committee really likes to preserve those.)

Comment: "_In C, void* is implicitly convertible to any pointer type, so this would work._" No, it works by definition.

Comment: Aha! The fact that pointers have different types is the key point I was overlooking. Thanks.